# Get user ID and locale without authorization

Tags: facebook, internationalization, locale

Can I get locale of facebook user (en_US etc.) on facebook iframe tab without prompting a log in window ?

I know that you can make translations of application and show application in user's language by default but on canvas apps, what about iframe tabs ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, locale is passed to Page Tabs in the `signed_request`. You can find more about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)